# Fetch all objects from list by list of ids using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of codes in one list and a list of object in another list. I want to fetch all the matching objects from list2 where the code is present in list1.

For eg:

```
class A{
private String code;
private String name;
}
List<A> list2;
List<String> codeList;
```

Now I want all the object of A from list2 for all the codes present in codeList.
I want to be able to use Java streams here to solve the problem instead of calling foreach code and fetching the object by equals method on code string.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Streams? To the best of my knowledge all natural stream solutions will have O(n²) running time. But if you sort both lists and then do a loop over *both* lists simultaneously you can get a O(n log n) running time. Maybe there is a hackish way to get that with streams also, but I cannot imagine a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a set and the filter by checking contains in set using stream.
Searching in set is constant complexity but in list it's O(n).

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(codeList);
List<A> res = list2.stream()
            .filter(e -> set.contains(e.getCode())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return list2.stream()
            .filter(listElement -> codeList.contains(listElement.getCode())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Depending on the number of items it might be a good idea to use a set instead of a list for codeList.

Comment: Yes. It also could be parallelized to make it faster using parallelStream()

Comment: I doubt that parallelStream would make much difference once a set is used, but you’d have to benchmark anyway.